# How can i update uithread from thread

Tags: android

I want to build android app that connects to a bluetooth device and prints "connected" on the `UI Thread` if the device successfuly connceted.
But i do not know how to transfer values between threads
can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several ways. The easiest is using `Activity.runOnUiThread()` method (see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) for more info).

You can accomplish this also using `Handler`s, which intercommunicate two different `Thread`s. You define the `Handler` in the UI Thread, pass it to the handler, and use it to send messages to the `UI Thread`. A good example might be found [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html).

You also have the possibility of using a local `BroadcastReceiver`. You simply define the receiver where you want to process the data (so, the UI thread) and process here whatever you want. A good example is [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html).

The 2 latter are based on `Intent`s, so you'll need to make sure the data you're passing implements `Serializable` or `Parcelable` or is a data type supported by `Intent`.

**---- EDIT ----**

To update your `TextView`, use something like this within your `Thread`. It will run the desired action in your `UI` Thread so you'll have no trouble updating `View`s from a `Thread`:

```
try {
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_textview);
      tv.setText("My text updated within a Thread");
    }
  });
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't understand how do i access my TextView from the connection activity if use the run on UI Method

Answer (score 1):

If you simply wants to show a toast in `UIThread`

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Kindly post your code and i will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use static variables it is the simplest way

Answer (score 0):

Use handler to post messages to main thread. in `onHandlemessage()` you can update main thread UI.  You can't update main thread UI from a thread.

Use [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) links for handler reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can opt for runOnUiThread as posted above and also I have used this for updating view from thread

```
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {  
    super.handleMessage(msg);  
    if(msg.what == 1) {  
        changeText(); //here you can make changes on UI
    }
}
```

just call it from thread as

```
textHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
```